# Android - Busybox architectures

Tags: android, arm, busybox

I want busybox on my emulator, but I'm not sure which one I should install.

I downloaded it fine from http://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/ and pushed it to the emulator using adb.

My emulator seems to be ARMv5:

```
$ ./adb shell busybox uname -m
armv5tejl
```

*Here are my questions*

1. How come that my busybox-armv6l works on my ARMv5 emulator?
2. Can I use busybox-armv6l on all Android phones?
3. If I want to target all Android phones, do I have to install different busybox?

Thank you very much for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The emulation is done by Qemu which can support armv6. Even if armv6 support is not enabled, the difference between armv5 and armv6 is mostly SIMD instructions which may not be used in the busybox-armv6l binary (they are mostly used when dealing with multimedia).
2. Probably, but you cannot be sure. I don't think I have ever seen Android running on a device with an armv5 CPU, but it is not impossible. If you want to target all possible devices, use an armv5 binary.
3. No, armv6/7 devices can run armv5 code and I don't really think busybox will get much of a performance improvement when compiled for armv6/7, so I would stick with a armv5 version.